# How to make nested list from one base list

Tags: c#, linq, cqrs

I would like to make nested list from this one list

`public class Product
{
    string Id;
    string ProductName;
    decimal Price;
    string Supplier;
    int Quantity;
    string VersionId;
    string TypeId;
}

public class ProductTypeDto
{
    public string TypeId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public List<ProductVersionDto> ProductVersions { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVersionDto
{
    public string VersionId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}`

I would like to know how I can create a list of **ProductTypeDto** using linq c# .
I need to get all products with the same  **TypeId** , and **ProductVersions** field should contain products with same version Id (and of course same TypeId).
I don't want to use foreach loops, and I dont want to loop over products twice to make this nested list.. I think there would be a better way using Linq, would be great if you can help.. 
Edit: I add here what I have done so far, but it is not the way I want this to be fixed.

```
List<ProductTypeDto> products = this._dbContext
            .Products
            .Where(product => product.TypeId == query.TypeId)
            .Select(product => new ProductTypeDto()
            {
                TypeId = product.TypeId,
                ProductName = product.ProductName,
                Price = product.Price,
                ProductVersions = product.Products.Where(p => p.TypeId == product.TypeId)
                                         .Select(p => new ProductVersionDto()
                                         {
                                             VersionId = p.VersionId,
                                             ProductName = p.ProductName,
                                             Supplier = p.Supplier,
                                             Quantity = p.Quantity
                                         }).ToList()
            })
            .ProjectTo<ProductTypeDto>(this._config)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

This is the result I want to get:

```
   var product1 = new Product() { Id = 1, ProductName = "foo", Price = 20, Supplier = "test1", Quantity = 3, VersionId = "1", TypeId = "1" };
    var product2 = new Product() { Id = 2, ProductName = "foo1", Price = 60, Supplier = "test2", Quantity = 9, VersionId = "1", TypeId = "1" };
    var product3 = new Product() { Id = 3, ProductName = "foo2", Price = 30, Supplier = "test3", Quantity = 5, VersionId = "2", TypeId = "1" };
    var product4 = new Product() { Id = 4, ProductName = "foo3", Price = 10, Supplier = "test4", Quantity = 4, VersionId = "1", TypeId = "2" };
    var product5 = new Product() { Id = 5, ProductName = "foo4", Price = 50, Supplier = "test5", Quantity = 8, VersionId = "1", TypeId = "3" };

    List<ProductVersionDto> p1 = {
        new ProductVersionDto { ProductName = "foo", Quantity= 3, Supplier ="test1"}
        new ProductVersionDto { ProductName = "foo1", Quantity= 9, Supplier ="test2"}
    };
    List<ProductVersionDto> p2 = {
        new ProductVersionDto { ProductName = "foo3", Quantity= 4, Supplier ="test4"}
    };
    List<ProductVersionDto> p3 = {
        new ProductVersionDto { ProductName = "foo4", Quantity= 8, Supplier ="test5"}
    };

    List<ProductTypeDto> products = {
        new ProductTypeDto{ ProductName = "foo", Price =20, ProductVersions = p1}
        new ProductTypeDto{ ProductName = "foo1", Price =60, ProductVersions = p1}
        new ProductTypeDto{ ProductName = "foo3", Price =10, ProductVersions = p2}
        new ProductTypeDto{ ProductName = "foo4", Price =50, ProductVersions = p3}
    }
```

Comment: I want to become president of USA, but without any efforts

Comment: can you share the sample of data with expect result.

Comment: @Mana but you have to show your efforts also, SO is not a spoonfeeding website. and please take my comment in a positive manner

Comment: @Mana - Viveknuna has a point. You tend to get better answers when you ask a better question. The degree of effort in posing the question also inspires more people to answer.

Comment: @Mana why `foo2` not exist in the expected result?

Comment: @sajid it should not be selected because we first get all products that have ``VersionId == 1``

Comment: @Mana i think for `p1`,`p2` and `p3` ok , but not for `products` result?

Comment: @Sajid but the goal is to only select products with a specific ``VersionId`` , so ``foo2`` should be eliminated from the first step..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dtos =
(
    from p in products
    group new ProductVersionDto()
    {
        VersionId = p.VersionId,
        ProductName = p.ProductName,
        Supplier = p.Supplier,
        Quantity = p.Quantity
    } by new { p.TypeId, p.ProductName, p.Price } into g
    select new ProductTypeDto()
    {
        TypeId = g.Key.TypeId,
        ProductName = g.Key.TypeId,
        Price = g.Key.Price,
        ProductVersions = g.ToList(),
    }
).ToList();
```

It appears that you meant `Price` to be a `decimal` in `ProductTypeDto`, BTW.